# Text files and sorting them out

Tags: python, sorting

This is my code:

```
names=[]
scores=[]
score_check=10

def class_name():
    print(input("What class are you in? [class1,class2,class3] "))
while True:
    class_name()
    choice=str(input("-->"))
    if class_name == "class1":
        load_data("class1")
    elif class_name == "class2":
        load_data("class2")
    elif class_name == "class3":
        load_data("class3")
    else:
        break


def main_menu():
    print("You have the following options")
    print("1)List in alphabetical order with each students highest score")
    print("2)List by the highest score, highest to lowest")
    print("3)List by the average score, highest to lowest")
    print("9)Exit")

def tidy_list(rough_list):
    new_list=[]
    for score in rough_list:
        new_list.append(int(score))
    return new_list

def load_data(group_name):
    text_file = open(group_name+".txt",'r')
    load_data(class_name)
    line=text_file.readline()
    while line:
     temp_line=line.split(',')
     names.append(line.split(',')[0])
     line=text_file.readline()
     temp_line.remove(temp_line[0])
     scores.append(tidy_list(temp_line))

def get_average(marks):
    total=0
    for score in marks:
        total= total+score
        return int(total/len(marks))

def score_vs_average():
    print("Score vs Average")
    highest_score=[]
    for student in scores:
        highest=max(student)
        highest_score.append(highest)
    print(highest_score)
    print(get_average(highest_score))
    print("Name Diff")

pos = 0
average=get_average(highest_score)
for name in names:
    print(name, abs(highest_score[pos]-average))
    pos = pos+1


while True:
    main_menu()
    choice=int(input("-->")) 
    if choice ==1:
        ()
    elif choice ==2:
        ()
    elif choice ==3:
        score_vs_average()
    else:
        break
```

I have three text files: `class1`, `class2` and `class3` - all containing a student name and score (e.g. John, 5).

I want to create a python program that:

1. Asks the user which class they would like to file.
2. Create a main menu to ask how they would like to sort that particular class.
3. Possible answers would be:

   - Sort in alphabetical order with each student's highest score
   - Sort from highest to lowest score
   - Sort by average score, highest to lowest.

I have attempted to this, but my brain is about to explode and I am really confused.

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code has at least one `IndentationError`, so it's not verifiable; it has a ton of stuff that clearly isn't relevant to your question, so it's not minimal; it also doesn't explain which part you're stuck on (and there are multiple parts left incomplete), so it's not even really an example.

Comment: The thread has been updated if it makes it easier to understand what im trying to do.

Comment: I have three classes, all of them contain scores and student names. I need to create a program that will ask what class i would like to sort, after I choose a class, i come up with a main menu on what they would like to sort. These three being either Alphabetical order with each student's highest score, sort from highest to lowest, or by average, highest to lowest. I have attempted to do this task, and this is my code, I am majorly stuck and i have tried everything, some things might not be relevant but i have tried.

Comment: Which bit is confusing you the most?  Try splitting your task down to its granular components.

Comment: You probably want 3 high-level functions - 1 that asks the user which class he wants to see, and return an identifier (probably the filename), another that asks how the user wants it sorted and returns another identifier (probably a string like 'alphabet', 'highest score', 'highest average'), and finally one that takes the output of the previous two functions as input, and applies the appropriate sorting to the appropriate file.  If you hit roadblocks trying to implement one of these functions, you'll be able to ask more concrete questions about that specific part.